# Iterating over yaml data in Middleman using Slim

Tags: slim-lang, middleman

I've got the following `index.slim` file:

```
---
title: Welcome to my site
---

ul.nav.nav-tabs
  = data.about.team
```

The output is `["John Doe", "Jane Monroe"]`, which is great.

Now how the heck do I iterate through this data using `slim` with Middleman?

I've tried the following but that doesn't work:

```
ul.nav.nav-tabs
  = data.about.team.each do |person|
    li = person
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer. Had to use `-` instead of that first `=`:

```
ul.nav.nav-tabs
  - data.about.team.each do |person|
  li = person
```

That's it. The `-` is used for executing Ruby code, and `=` for printing the result of a Ruby operation.